# iOS 6 Readiness Checklist

Tags: iphone, ios6

Can anyone tell where the iOS 6 Readiness Checklist is?  It was referenced in the iOS 6 developer email sent by Apple earlier today but I can't find the actual checklist on developer.apple.com, using a Google search or in searching Apple's Developer Forums. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probably this page?](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/pre-release/) It requires you log in with a developer account to access it.

Notice the "checklist" in the url:
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/pre-release/